# How to configure LISTENER in Oracle DB 21c XE?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle21c

I have installed Oracle 21c XE in Windows 10, and I'm trying to create a new database using DBCA,

Here on selecting the listener from this window it's status shown as **Down** even though LISTENER is still on active as we can see below.

[image]

**From Command Line:**

```
PS C:\Users\ABC.lab> lsnrctl start LISTENER

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 19-JUL-2023 08:45:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
```

**From Services window:**

[image]

**listener.ora file as:**

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\ABC.lab\product\21c\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\ABC.lab\product\21c\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = monarch.ABC.lab)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Though the LISTENER is still active it says the below error on command line

```
PS C:\Users\ABC.lab> lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 19-JUL-2023 08:40:34

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=monarch.ABC.lab)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-01153: Failed to process string: PGD~É
```

Could you please guide me how to create a new database with active listener ?